# Best way to truncate a binary number

Tags: python, binary

The intended result is to have the last `k` bits of a number of arbitrary size `n` set to zero. For example, if I'd like to truncate `0b10011101` by 3, the result would be `0b10011000`.

I thought of a few possible solutions, like using shifts and other binary operators, or even string manipulation. Two of them are as follows:

```
def truncate_bin_shift(n, k):
    return n >> k << k
```

```
def truncate_bin_and(n, k):
    return n & ((1<<n.bit_length()-k)-1 << k)
```

My favorite one is the shift forward and back, given how clean it is, but I wonder if there is any other alternative that could be significantly more efficient for larger values of `n`.

The question is whether any of these could be considered an efficient and appropriate (read pythonic) way to accomplish it.

If not, what would be a better way, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```
def truncate_bin_shift(n, k):
    return n & -1 << k
```

I personally like it better because it uses each parameter only once, and uses `&` to mask the bits, which is more how truncating (resetting bits) is usually performed.

Comment: How would a negative number be presented in binary?

Comment: Negative numbers are represented in binary with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).